# How to always show scroll bar when content overflows using css or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

Currently, `overflow: auto` only reveals scroll bar when user starts scrolling and hides the bar after scrolling event finishes on mobile (on android at least, don't know iOS).

I previously thought there is no css rule could always show scroll bar when overflow occurs and hide the bar when content fits. Today I bumped into [this website](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2017/09/14/asynchronous-recursion.html), and if you check its mobile site, it's code blocks does exactly what I wanted. I quickly checked it's css rule, and it's also `overflow: auto`. So I'm wondering is there any special trick in css that can always show scroll bar when overflow occurs. If not, is there any concise vanilla JavaScript code that could realize this effect.

Comment: Did you try your out own suggestion of `overflow: auto` in your CSS before posting this question? [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Comment: Yes, on my website and on the MDN page you refereed to, this rule does exactly what I described in the post: scroll bar will not always show when overflow occurs in mobile (android) browsers. That's why I though it is designed to be so.

Comment: Aah. Yes, you mean the mobile implementation of scrollbar that times out and disappears after about 1/2 second? I think if you just style the scrollbar, it will quit doing that. [CSS Scrollbars](https://scotch.io/tutorials/customize-the-browsers-scrollbar-with-css)

Comment: @skylize Styling scroll bar does the trick. MDN suggests not to use it on production site so I guess I will leave the scroll bar untouched on my site. Anyway it is good to know styling scroll bar prevents it from disappearing on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

try `overflow-y: scroll;`

reference: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/force-vertical-scrollbar/

Comment: It always shows a scroll bar even if the content fits the container. Not really what I want.

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted sorry